# How do i add a node js backend to a flutter app?

Tags: node.js, flutter, backend

i am a new flutter dev and I want to understand how to connect a backend of node js to my flutter app. do I set routes and controllers and models like I would normally in a web app?

Answer (score 0):

you can create `api endpoint` (in server-side) to connect your app with backend
just call api in mobile app with specific parameters.
normal web app usually returns you `html` page, but you need `JSON` file only
(sometime you can parse html file to grab data **but not prefer**).

api that you created (with `Node.js`/`ASP.net`/`PHP`/`Python` and etc) just return `JSON` type data and client (mobile app) get data and draw ui or do another operation with it

Comment: Yeah. that's what i figured. i think a REST API would be excellent. So I don't use routers and controllers to redirect based on clicks and taps like I would on a web page?

Comment: @M.Hagos `Controllers` and `Routers` will be same as before, imagine you have `MVC` architecture, you define `Route`,`Controller`,`Model` and at least `View`,
In normal `Web app`,Server render `View` according to data that come from `Controller` and `Model`
in your case, `View` is no longer need because you don't need html,
`Controller` just Returns you a bunch of `JSON` object
[See this repo to understand `REST` api with `Node.js`](https://github.com/StephenGrider/FullstackReactCode/tree/master/server)

Comment: So that means i write the controllers and model in the flutter app right? so the node is just for connecting to database and fetching JSON files right?

Comment: The whole app is going to be in flutter including all the mcv components and I only connect to the node server to fetch data. am I understanding it right?

Comment: the models will get JSON data from  a database or something but the models themselves, and the controllers and routers will be in flutter (dart) right?

Comment: @M.Hagos it's all up to you, BTW Cant Save Data in `Flutter` as same as `Model` in backend.
`ClientApp`(like `iOS App`,`Android App`,`Web App`,`Desktop App` and etc) only act as `View`, Just Showing Data depend on their own logic.
`ClientApp` use `REST` to interact with backed and database.
Just call api and get Data to showing them in client-side.